# Displaying a bus in Verilog

Tags: verilog, hdl

I'm writing a code in Verilog which would count till 15 on every edge of a clock and would go back to 0. However, I'm not able to display waveforms. All I can see is Z (high impedance).

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps


module Counter(
input ck,
output [3:0] a

);

reg a;

reg [3:0] i = 4'b0000;
always@(posedge ck)
begin
    a = i;

    if(i==15)
    i = 0;

    else
    i = i+1;
end

endmodule
```

Here is the testbench to drive it:

```
module Counter_tb;

wire clock;
wire [3:0] ta;

Clocker mygate(.clk(clock));

Counter mygate2(.ck(clock), .a(ta));

initial
begin
    $display(ta, clock);

end
endmodule
```

The waveform of clock is displayed properly, but not ta. What could be the possible mistake?

Comment: Change `$display` to `$monitor`

Comment: $monitor wasn't helping in the first place...it was monitor only that was showing the Z output everywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declared `a` twice, once as an 4-bit output (inferred wire type), and once a an internal single bit reg. The way you did it is non-compliant with the IEEE standard because is does not follow the ANSI or non-ANSI style. Some simulators may allow what you did and work correctly, others throw compiling errors (strict IEEE compliance), and some get confused. I'm guessing the latter is what happened with your simulator; maybe there was a warning message in your compile log you over looked.

Get rid of the line `reg a;` and change `output [3:0] a` to `output reg [3:0] a` to make it compatible with an ANSI style header. With an ANSI portlist style, the ports direction, type, width, and name are declared on the same name.

```
module Counter(
input ck,
output reg [3:0] a
);
```

The Alternative is the Non-ANSI style (not recommended), which is required one line for declaring the port order, another for the direction & size, and a optional additional line to make it a reg. A proper Non-ANSI style header below.The Non-ANSI style header is required with IEEE1364-1995. ANSI was added and became the recommended styles since IEEE1364-2001, with non-ANSI supported so legacy code could continue being used.

```
module Counter(ck, a);
input ck;
output [3:0] a;
reg [3:0] a;
```

---

Other note, flops should be assigned with non-blocking (`<=`) assignments, instead of blocking (`=`) assignments. At minimum change `a = i;` to `a <= i;` to get in the practice of proper coding style that will avoid race conditions in the verilog scheduler.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I'll take note of those standards you mentioned. One thing, the output is showing in hexadecimal. After displaying 10, it starts from a,b...till f. Then again rolls back to 0. What could be the reason for that?

Comment: For `$monitor` and `$display` statement you can use a format expression; example `$monitor("ta:%0d clk:%b", ta, clock);`. Refer to [IEEE Std 1800-2012](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf) section 21.2 _Display system tasks_ for full details. In waveform there is usually option to change the base from hex to dec or bin, etc. but it is specific to the particular waveform tool

Answer (score 0):

You call "$display" once at time 0. What you are expecting to see?
Try to change $display to "$monitor(ta, clock);".

Comment: $monitor wasn't helping in the first place...it was monitor only that was showing the Z output everywhere.